# How to add attachment to CouchDB using Couchdb4j library

Tags: java, javascript, couchdb

How can I use Java application to add system files as an attachment to Couchdb database using Couchdb4J library?

I tried modifying the sample code below but there's an unresolved error. Does anybody know where's my mistake and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fourspaces.couchdb.CouchResponse;
import com.fourspaces.couchdb.Database;
import com.fourspaces.couchdb.Document;
import com.fourspaces.couchdb.Session;

public class FileScanner {

Session priceListDocsSession = new Session("localhost",5984);
  Database db = priceListDocsSession.getDatabase("filesdb");

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  FileScanner fs = new FileScanner();

 fs.processDir(new File("C:\\CouchDB"));
}

void processDir(File f) {
if (f.isFile()) {
  Map<String, Object> doc = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  doc.put("name", f.getName());
  doc.put("path", f.getAbsolutePath());
  doc.put("size", f.length());


  db.saveDocument(doc);
  InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
  String att=db.putAttachment(doc.getId(),doc.getRev(),f,is);
   } 
else {
  File[] fileList = f.listFiles();
  if (fileList == null) return;
  for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
    try {
      processDir(fileList[i]);
     } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
        }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

The errors appears on the `db.saveDocument(doc);`

and

`String att=db.putAttachment(doc.getId(),doc.getRev(),f,is);` saying that `.getId()` and `getRev()` is undefined for the type Map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fixed the problem by adding some of the jcouchdb dependencies on the classpath.